# Sending user notifications to Android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I built an Android app, actually a hybrid app, so it's essentially an Android app that has a webview pointing to my mobile site. The app has some user-based functionality where users communicate with other users. Currently, an email with a permalink goes out as a notification when a user talks to another user.

I'm wondering if it's possible to send a notification to the user's Android device if they have the app installed. I'd need to send the notification based on the userid the notification is meant for. What does it take to add this in?

1. Do I need to store a mapping of the device id/user id in my database?
2. Can I use the notifications API as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: You want to send notification from internet to a device? If so, use `Push Notifications`.

Comment: Yeah for example, in the 500px.com app, when someone likes my photo, I get a notification on my phone.  Is that done using push notifications?

Comment: I haven't used the app but i think so.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors to this question, the simplest solution at this time seems to be using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) which lets you push messages to installed apps.

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for a tutorial.